# How do I force a 404 from the symfony routing in YML without specifying a custom controller?

Tags: symfony, routes, httpresponse, http-status-codes

## Problem to solve

I want to force to trigger a `404` for a certain specific route in symfony, without having to specify a custom controller that just throws the exception, and before the router continues to explore the rest of the routing file.

Can I say that in the `routing.yml` file for a specific route?

## Context

I have this routing for form submitting in my travel agency:

```
POST /submit/{submitterForm}
```

where `submitterForm` can only take 2 values: `purchase-trip` and `contact` depending on if the visitor submits a form in a page where he is visiting a trip or from the contact page. For example `POST /submit/contact` would be valid.

I have this other route:

```
GET /{destinationSeoUri}/{tripSeoUri}
```

to display a specific trip for a destination. For example `GET /thailand/trip-bangkok-beaches` would be valid.

## Limiting values from the router

This is the relevant extract of my `routing.yml`:

```
submit:
    path: /submit/{submitterForm}
    methods: [ POST ]
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:DataSubmission:submit }
    requirements:
        submitterForm: purchase-trip|contact

trip:
    path: /{destinationSeoUri}/{tripSeoUri}
    methods: [ GET ]
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Trip:trip }
```

## What I want

For any `POST` request with an invalid value of `{submitterForm}` in the route `/submit/{submitterForm}` I want that the system returns a `404 Not Found`

It does not happen now because when the router does not match the `submit` route pattern, it still falls down to the next ones and then matches the `trip` pattern.

Then, the system says "okey, I have a route that matches, instead, this is only allowed for GET, so I'll respond a `405 Method not allowed`".

This would hold true for something like `POST /thailand/trip-bangkok-beaches` but I want to specifically signal the client that if the `POST` matches the `/submit/any-invalid-form-submitter-name` it is then a Not Found.

## Initial solution

To do so, I've inserted, in order, in the middle of the previous two, a catch-all for `/submit/*` like in this routing excerpt:

```
submit:
    path: /submit/{submitterForm}
    methods: [ POST ]
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:DataSubmission:submit }
    requirements:
        submitterForm: purchase-trip|contact

submit_fallback:
    path: /submit/{submitterForm}
    methods: [ POST ]
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:DataSubmission:notFound }

trip:
    path: /{destinationSeoUri}/{tripSeoUri}
    methods: [ GET ]
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Trip:trip }
```

This way, requesting to `POST /submit/any-invalid-form-submitter-name` is matched by the `submit_fallback` route.

### The controller

The controller is a pretty simple "on-liner":

```
{
    throw new NotFoundHttpException();
}
```

## Preferred solution

I think I'm looking for something similar to this:

```
submit_fallback:
    path: /submit/{submitterForm}
    methods: [ POST ]
    status: 404
```

## So, questions

- Is it possible for me to tell the `submit_fallback` something like: ***hey guy you don't need a `_controller` just because you have to send a `404 Not found` (or any other status I would want) and nothing else.***
- If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add requirements onto your other route so that `destinationSeoUri` cannot equal `submit`. This should force that route to not match, and throw the 404 instead of the 405 error.

```
trip:
    path: /{destinationSeoUri}/{tripSeoUri}
    methods: [ GET ]
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Trip:trip }
    requirements:
        destinationSeoUri: "^(?!submit$)"
```

Comment: The $ should go inside, I feel. `"^(?!submit$)"` according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936364/javascript-regular-expression-to-negate-an-exact-string-match - But anyway, the "negative requirement tip" deserves the selection as the proper answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment; I tested this and you are correct, so I have updated my answer accordingly. Nice catch 4 years later!

Comment: Backlog has a pile of issues in queue... this week was time for this one hahahah - Thanks for updating the answer.