# JavaScript regular expression to negate an exact string match

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation

Is there a way in HTML (JavaScript) to write a regular expression to negate an exact string match?

I would like to make sure an input is not equal to "`foo`". Only "`foo`" must fail validation, but "`fooo`" must be allowed.

In other words, I'm looking for a negation of this regex:

`<input pattern="^foo$" ...>`

Comment: You can use a negative lookahead: `<input pattern="^(?!foo$)" ...>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 pattern exclude words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875922/html5-pattern-exclude-words)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work: https://codepen.io/smatric/pen/mprBMd

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible way is combining start of string anchor (`^`) with negative lookahead that includes both the target string and end of string anchor (`$`):

```
/^(?!foo$)/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/U5hglQ/1).

But `pattern` pattern is funny in that account - it has to match something in the string, that's why the original approach doesn't work. This does work, however:

```
<input pattern="(?!foo$).*">
```

Comment: This does not allow "fooo"

Comment: This does allow `fooo`, check the demo (or just run `/^(?!foo$)/.test('fooo')` in console). Empty string is matched, yes, as `^` is _anchor_.

Comment: Sorry, you are right - didn't see the empty match. Too early in the morning ;-)

Comment: No problem, has woken up a bit early too. )

Comment: I can see your regex works in the demo you linked to, but for some reason, it doesn't work in HTML: https://codepen.io/smatric/pen/mprBMd

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about that difference. I'm not even sure it's not a bug of either spec or implementation. ) Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If Javascript is allowed, why not just negate the result of the match?

```
if (!yourString.match(/^foo$/)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: That won't work since it won't allow `fooo` as well. But it can easily be fixed: `/^foo$/`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
\bfooo\b
```